# Show additional image in netsuite

Tags: netsuite, product

Is there a way to show multiple images of a product on product description page in netsuite.

Or, is there a short tag available to use in category template to show more images of product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of my project we had to implement the same scenario, but Netsuite doesn't have such built in capability. There is only one display image option for each item. One of our client wanted to have multiple images of the product   on the webstore. We just figured out some alternative by uploading all our images to Amazon S3 and integrate to our website. It worked for us.